# Opencv giving a C++ exception error with LBPHFaceRecognizer

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

i am trying face recognition with opencv's LBPH with GUI made by tkinter. the first time my program runs . but when i exit camera with 'q' button and start again with push button in GUI it gives error. i have tried many workarounds but still no answer. can someone help me out?
HERE IS MY CODE

```
recognizer.read('C:/data.yml')
id = 0
# set text style
fontface = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
fontscale = 1
fontcolor = (203, 23, 252)
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
name_to_track=value_.get()
print(name_to_track)
# get data from sqlite by ID
while (True):
    # camera read
    ret, img = cam.read()
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    result = face.process(rgb)

    if result.detections:
        for id_, detect in enumerate(result.detections):
            bbox_ = detect.location_data.relative_bounding_box
            ih, iw, ic = img.shape
            bbox = int(bbox_.xmin * iw), int(bbox_.ymin * ih), \
                   int(bbox_.width * iw), int(bbox_.height * ih)
            x = bbox[0]
            y = bbox[1]
            w = bbox[2]
            h = bbox[3]
            cv2.rectangle(img, bbox, (255, 0, 255), 2)
            img_size=gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            img_size=np.array(img_size)
            print("x:"+str(x)+"y:"+str(y))
            if(x<0 or y<0 or w <0 or h<0):
                continue
            id, conf = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y + h, x:x + w])

            #print(conf)
            if (conf < 50):
                profile = getProfile(id)
                # set text to window
                if (profile != None):
                    # cv2.PutText(cv2.fromarray(img),str(id),(x+y+h),font,(0,0,255),2);
                    cv2.putText(img, "ID: " + str(profile[0]) + ' Acc:' + str(round(float(1 - conf / 100), 2)),
                                (x, y + h + 30), fontface, fontscale, fontcolor, 2)
                    if (profile[1] == name_to_track):
                        cv2.putText(img, "Tracking", (x, y + h + 60), fontface, fontscale, fontcolor, 2)
                    else:
                        cv2.putText(img, "Name " + str(profile[1]), (x, y + h + 60), fontface, fontscale, fontcolor, 2)


            else:
                cv2.putText(img, "Unknown", (x, y + h + 30), fontface, fontscale, [255, 0, 0], 2)

    cv2.imshow("face", img)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

THANKS!!

Comment: you forgot the exception